# A lower bound for $\log\left( \frac{a+x^2}{b+x^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

I am looking for a tight lower bound for

$$f(x)=\log\left( \frac{a+x^2}{b+x^2} \right)$$

$x>0$ and $1<b<<a$. I didn't check for convexity analytically, but I plotted this function versus $x$ in MATLAB and it was convex and strictly decreasing. I am looking for a lower bound that has  relatively simple, like quadratic ... .

Comment: What's your application and how tight do you want it to be?

Comment: And for what $x$ does the bound have to hold?

Comment: What is the problem of using $\log(1+x)$? I assume you want bounds that do not use $\log$, what other functions do you want to allow/disallow?

Comment: I want to calculate expectation of $\log(1+x)$, where $x$ is a complicated function of another variable.

Comment: $x$ is large, say more than 100.

Comment: 'x is a complicated function of another variable' - then it's not $x$, it's some $h(x)$. What exactly function is it? This may help.

Comment: $x=\frac{a}{c+by^2}$, expectation is over $y$, the values of $x=f(y)$ are large.

Comment: is the lower bound $\dfrac{2x}{2+x}$ better?

Comment: You could use $$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}$$ Since it is an alternating  series, we know the sum alternates above and below the actual value of $\ln(1+x)$ until it converges at infinity. The times it goes below the actual value of $\ln(1+x)$ is on each addition of a term with even index. Hence $$\ln(1+x) \geq \sum_{n=1}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}$$ the sum will get arbitrarily close to $\ln(1+x)$ the larger you let $k$ get.

Comment: @abel How did you get that lower bound?

Comment: use the midpoint rule on $\ln(1+x) = \int_1^{1+x} \dfrac{dt}{t}$

Comment: Notice that since $\frac{1}{t}$ is convex, we have: $$\log\frac{a}{b}=\int_{b}^{a}\frac{dt}{t}\leq\frac{a-b}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)=\frac{a^2-b^2}{2ab}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry, I didn't get what you are saying, can you explain more?

Comment: The integral of a convex function over $[a,b]$ is bounded by the integral of the linear function through the endpoints. $\frac{1}{t}$ is convex. That gives $$\log\frac{a}{b}\leq\frac{a^2-b^2}{2ab}$$ for every $a>b>0$.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean, too.